# Why am I getting undefined control sequence when using fncychap Glenn style?

Tags: table-of-contents, fncychap

Hi everyone and thank you for reading me,

I am playing around with a phd thesis latex template and I am trying to set the Glenn chapter style from the fncychap package. The problem is that when I try to compile with it the following error comes up:

```
 ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
\@mkboth ...nguage {\languagename }}\def \bbl@arg 
                                                  {#1}\ifx \bbl@arg \@empty ...l.199 \tableofcontents

                   % Prints the main table of contents
```

Nonetheless, I should note that this only happens when using the Glenn style, as any other does not produce the error.

A working example may be found in overleaf as this is part of a somehow complicated phd theses template: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl#.Wu7w3y-mN26

Just add `\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}` to that template and you get the error.

Any one's got a clue on this one?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: This looks like it *could* be an outdated `babel` version, so you could check for updates. But it is really hard to tell without a minimal document that reproduces the error (an MWE, see samcarter's link above).

Comment: I've edited the original question, thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: Class and package are not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you.

A solution working was to redefined "\tableofcontents" as :

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
  \null\hfill\textbf{\Large\contentsname}\hfill\null\par % line to comment if Glenn style also wanted here
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother
```

By default, the title "Contents" is center,
If you want it to be like others (with Glenn style) : comment the 3rd line

To call the table of contents:

```
\chapter*{Table of Contents} %if you want in Glenn style also
\tableofcontents
```

Jerome

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Your answer seems quite helpful. Nevertheless, could you eleborate on why your redefinition of `\tableofcontents`solves?

Comment: @Dave It's used in .sty file : `\ChTitleUpperCase`
It seems that this command, which makes use of the `\MakeUppercase` command for the title display, makes the switch command fragile. One way to overcome this difficulty is to redefined the `\tableofcontents` command to make the switch command robust. For what it's worth, I would probably not trust `fncychap` for a longer document, it has fairly rudimentary errors. I might recommend instead using the `titlesec package` or the `memoir class` (among other options) for customizing headers.